# How would you create the equivalent of this nested javascript array in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

[[1,2,[3]],4] we can declare an array like this in Javascript, how would this array be written in Java? the following is something like what i want but does not work as 4 is not a 2d array. Is there a way to do this without lists?

```
int[][] arrayNestedTest = {{1,2},{3}};
int[][][] arrayNestedTest1 = {arrayNestedTest, 4};
```

Thanks

Comment: No, that won't really work in Java

Comment: why would you need to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, `Java` doesn't work like that

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: You can't put `4` in an array of `int[]`.

Comment: OK, I will be doing an online test for a job soon, they say there will be some basic tests like flatten an array of arbitrarily nested arrays of integers into a flat array of integers. e.g. [[1,2,[3]],4] -> [1,2,3,4].

I have heard in the test they allow you use a language of your choice.. I like Java so i said i would try recreate the problem in Java for practice, until my mind got lost trying to do it.

Comment: It's pretty overly complicated, as per @JonasW.'s answer. My suggestion would be to not make `Java` your language of choice I guess unless you want to complicate your life

Comment: I presume if I choose Java they may have different tests, not really sure. I have learned it in javascript anyway which i much handier. more so curious

Comment: @isaac agreed. I personally would fail to write something working  in Java because I would confuse the `public static void main(String[] args)` thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper class that either contains the Int itself or an array of other nodes:

```
class Node {
  Integer value;
  Node[] children;
  Node(Node[] ...children) { this.children = children; }
  Node(Integer value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

So you can build it up as:

```
Node nested = new Node(
  new Node( new Node(1), new Node(2), new Node( new Node(3) ) ),
  new Node(4)
);
```

But it is really complicated to work with these nodes now.

Answer (score 0):

You need the last term to be in an `int[][]`, and you can do it with something like

```
int[][] arrayNestedTest = { { 1, 2 }, { 3 } };
int[][][] arrayNestedTest1 = { arrayNestedTest, { { 4 } } };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayNestedTest1));
```

Outputs

```
[[[1, 2], [3]], [[4]]]
```

Comment: would also like to know why this was down voted, seems like a good answer?